# Rendering Javascript in an asp.net master page at a specific spot

Tags: javascript, master-pages, rendering

I've a specific requirement of rendering Javascript onto a master page of an asp.net site. There are two specific requirements of it:

1) The position - It should be rendered at the very end of the page just before BODY tag
2) Control - Render it only when requested.

I solved #2 by creating a web-part which will render the javascript only when its placed on the page. But I could not achieve #1 since the web part doesn't give me control over where to render the javascript inside body tag.

Did anyone solve this problem before?

Please advice.

Thanks
Sachit

Answer (score 1):

Try using [ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx), it injects the script right above the </body> tag.

Comment: That gives me only control over when to render....but not where to render....Both are important requirements for me :(

Comment: @Sachit - if by "where" you mean which pages to render it on...I would suggest having a helper function that registers the script, then programmatically call the helper function on pages that need to render it.

Comment: actually by where I meant the exact location of the script. I need this script to be the one just above </body> tag. I think I can get close to this by using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript but looks like I can not control the order of scripts if I've multiple which is a problem since I've many scripts on that page and I want this one to be at the bottom.

Comment: If you have multiples, use a Strinbuilder to combine them in the order you need, and then use this.

Comment: actually let me tell rest of the story....this is a sharepoint master page, so I've no control over what and how SharePoint renders rest of the scripts, styles etc...

Answer (score 0):

[RenderControl](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx) is the last method to return in MasterPage Event Lifecycle that you can override.  My guess would be to put it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Master Page, then why not put a content place holder just before the end body tag? The content pages should render their JavaScript in that particular place holder.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">    


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="headerContent" runat="server"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="mainForm" runat="server">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="mainContent" runat="server" /> 
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="footerContent" runat="server" />       
    </form>    

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="footerJsContent" runat="server"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Content pages should render their JavaScript inside the footerJsContent place holder.